# Google Analytics called twice on React web apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I have a web apps (blog) and built it using React (React-starter-kit). After deploying and adding GA on my Html.js, I checked the site using Tag Assistant by Google and found out that after opening my homepage and redirecting to article detail page, the GA Tag is called again (the one with UA-.......).

Below is the snippet of my code in Html.js for adding GA:

```
 <body>
                <div id="app" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: children }} />
                <script
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `window.App=${serialize(app)}` }}
                    />
                {scripts.map(script => <script key={script} src={script} />)}
                {config.analytics.googleTrackingId && (
                    <script
                      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html:
                          'window.ga=function(){ga.q.push(arguments)};ga.q=[];ga.l=+new Date;' +
                          `ga('create','${
                            config.analytics.googleTrackingId
                          }','auto');ga('send','pageview')`,
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                {config.analytics.googleTrackingId && (
                    <script
                        src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"
                        async
                        defer
                    />
                )}
```

I suspect that the cause of the GA code being detected 2 times is the routing and Html.js being re rendered again.

How can I rectify this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to move your Google analytics code outside of your component. Some react starter kits have a place holder for the analytics code, you can see if yours does the same. What is the repo to your starter kit?

Comment: I used this one : https://reactstarter.com/, could you advise ?

Comment: You can add your analytics code in `/src/config.js`  line 41 https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/config.js#L39

Comment: ehm, yes, added the analytics code there the ID. However, the problem as shown in the above code, I send a pageview to GA and used that ID from the config.js. However, when i move from 1 compnent to the other, the GA code to send the pageview gets called twice